# GCP service account key rotation through secret manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-secret-manager

I have a service account in GCP and I hold its key in a Secret Manager.

Is there a way to set a scheduled secret rotation for that secret holding service account key, so the Pub/Sub would be a GCP one, and not managed by me? Does GCP provide such a managed Pub/Sub service?

Comment: The short answer is: no, there is nothing to rotate automatically secret, only tool to remind you to do it. However, why are you storing a service account key file in Google Cloud? AFAIK, it's a dead lock pattern: to access the secret, you need a credential. That credential is stored in Secret manager. To access the secret, you need a credential,....

Comment: the secret can be accessed by user accounts, which then in turn run application that uses the service account

Comment: Use impersonation, or allow the user account (or a group of account) to access to the same resource as the service account. I'm a service account key file hater, when I can advocate to avoid them, I do!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function for that, but Google advises using tool such as [Keyrotator](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/help-keep-your-google-cloud-service-account-keys-safe#:%7E:text=these%20best%20practices.-,key%20rotation,-Keyrotator%20is%20a) to keep the Service Account keys safe.
You can also write your own script using Cloud SDK that will create a new key, obtain it and update it in the Secrets Manager:

```
# create the key
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key-file \
    --iam-account=sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# obtain new key
gcloud beta iam service-accounts keys get-public-key KEY_ID \
    --iam-account=SA_NAME --output-file=FILENAME

#update the secret in secrets manager
gcloud secrets update secret-id \
    --update-labels=key=value

# remove the old one
gcloud iam service-accounts keys disable key-id \
    --iam-account=sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This is of course a simplified code, you can find more information on those commands here - [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), [2](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secrets).
Such script can be run periodically, e.g. using crontab on a GCE instance or [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine).

Comment: Actually Google [advises against](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys#secret-manager) storing service account keys in Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

@david - Doppler actually supports automatic secrets rotation for GCP Cloud SQL — including MySQL, Postgres, and SQL Server. Also, since Cloud SQL has a rich admin API, the rotation can be performed entirely through the API - no serverless proxy required!

Hope this helps
https://docs.doppler.com/docs/gcp_cloudsql